# Draw a graphic from a R function

Tags: r, function, graphics

I'm trying to draw a graphic from this function which I made:

```
f=function(x)
    {
    m=0
    n=1
    o=0
    for(i in 1:x){
        o=m+n
        m=n
        n=o
    }
 }
```

Tried using plot and curve functions but always getting error messages

Comment: It currently cannot draw anything since `f` does not return anything...
Did you try running `print(f(10))`? I just get `NULL`
Please, add more contestual info (what should `f` do?) and also attach code you used to "draw" `f` (how did you use `plot` and `curve`?)
WIthout these info I think it will be very hard helping you

Comment: I'm just computing Fibonnacci numbers. I used `print(o)` in the beggining and it showed the correct numbers, now I want to do the graphic. Just tried `plot(f(10))`, that worked with other functions I made

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to be computing the Fibonnaci numbers.
After correcting your function, the following works.

```
f <- function(x){
  m <- 0
  n <- 1
  o <- 0
  for(i in 1:x){
    o <- m + n
    m <- n
    n <- o
  }
  n
}

g <- Vectorize(f, 'x')

plot(1:10, g(1:10), type = "l")
```

Comment: Tried this and got this message

`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Don't know what's wrong